# Python readinto: How to convert from an array.array to a custom ctype structure

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes, python-2.x

I have created an array of integers and I would like them to be interpreted by the structure definition which I have created

```
from ctypes import *
from array import array

class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("init", c_uint),
                ("state", c_char),
                ("constant", c_int),
                ("address", c_uint),
                ("size", c_uint),
                ("sizeMax", c_uint),
                ("start", c_uint),
                ("end", c_uint),
                ("timestamp", c_uint),
                ("location", c_uint),
                ("nStrings", c_uint),
                ("nStringsMax", c_uint),
                ("maxWords", c_uint),
                ("sizeFree", c_uint),
                ("stringSizeMax", c_uint),
                ("stringSizeFree", c_uint),
                ("recordCount", c_uint),
                ("categories", c_uint),
                ("events", c_uint),
                ("wraps", c_uint),
                ("consumed", c_uint),
                ("resolution", c_uint),
                ("previousStamp", c_uint),
                ("maxTimeStamp", c_uint),
                ("threshold", c_uint),
                ("notification", c_uint),
                ("version", c_ubyte)]

# arr = array.array('I', [1])
# How can I do this?
# mystr = MyStruct(arr) magic
# (mystr.helloworld == 1) == True
```

I can do the following:

```
mystr = MyStruct()
rest = array.array('I')
with open('myfile.bin', 'rb') as binaryFile:
    binaryFile.readinto(mystr)
    rest.fromstring(binaryFile.read())

# Now create another struct with rest
rest.readinto(mystr) # Does not work
```

How can I avoid using a file to convert an array of Ints to a struct if the data is contained in an array.array('I')? I am not sure what the Structure constructor accepts or how the readinto works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1: Star unpacking for one-line initialization

Star-unpacking will work, but only if all the fields in your structure are integer types. In Python 2.x, `c_char` cannot be initialized from an `int` (it works fine in 3.5). If you change the type of `state` to `c_byte`, then you can just do:

```
mystr = MyStruct(*myarr)
```

This doesn't actually benefit from any `array` specific magic (the values are briefly converted to Python `int`s in the unpacking step, so you're not reducing peak memory usage), so you'd only bother with an `array` if initializing said `array` was easier than directly reading into the structure for whatever reason.

If you go the star unpacking route, reading `.state` will now get you `int` values instead of len 1 `str` values. If you want to initialize with `int`, but read as one character `str`, you can use a protected name wrapped in a `property`:

```
class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [...
                ("_state", c_byte),  # "Protected" name int-like; constructor expects int
                ...]

    @property
    def state(self):
        return chr(self._state)

    @state.setter
    def state(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, basestring):
            x = ord(x)
        self._state = x
```

A similar technique could be used without `property`s by defining your own `__init__` that converted the `state` argument passed:

```
class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("init", c_uint),
                ("state", c_char),
                ...]

    def __init__(self, init=0, state=b'\0', *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(state, basestring):
            state = chr(state)
        super(MyStruct, self).__init__(init, state, *args, **kwargs)
```

### Solution #2: Direct `memcpy`-like solutions to reduce temporaries

You can use some `array` specific magic to avoid the temporary Python level `int`s though (and avoid the need to change `state` to `c_byte`) without real file objects using a fake (in-memory) file-like object:

```
import io

mystr = MyStruct()  # Default initialize

# Use BytesIO to gain the ability to write the raw bytes to the struct
# because BytesIO's readinto isn't finicky about exact buffer formats
io.BytesIO(myarr.tostring()).readinto(mystr)

# In Python 3, where array implements the buffer protocol, you can simplify to:
io.BytesIO(myarr).readinto(mystr)
# This still performs two memcpys (one occurs internally in BytesIO), but
# it's faster by avoiding a Python level method call
```

This only works because your non-`c_int` width attributes are followed by `c_int` width attributes (so they're padded out to four bytes anyway); if you had two `c_ubyte`/`c_char`/etc. types back to back, then you'd have problems (because one value of the `array` would initialize two fields in the struct, which does not appear to be what you want).

If you were using Python 3, you could benefit from `array` specific magic to avoid the cost of both unpacking and the two step `memcpy` of the `BytesIO` technique (from `array` -> `bytes` -> struct). It works in Py3 because Py3's `array` type supports the buffer protocol (it didn't in Py2), and because Py3's `memoryview` features a `cast` method that lets you change the format of the `memoryview` to make it directly compatible with `array`:

```
mystr = MyStruct()  # Default initialize

# Make a view on mystr's underlying memory that behaves like a C array of
# unsigned ints in native format (matching array's type code)
# then perform a "memcpy" like operation using empty slice assignment
# to avoid creating any Python level values.
memoryview(mystr).cast('B').cast('I')[:] = myarr
```

Like the `BytesIO` solution, this only works because your fields all happen to pad to four bytes in size

### Performance

Performance-wise, star unpacking wins for small numbers of fields, but for large numbers of fields (your case has a couple dozen), direct `memcpy` based approaches win out; in tests for a 23 field class, the `BytesIO` solution won over star unpacking on my Python 2.7 install by a factor of 2.5x (star unpacking was 2.5 microseconds, `BytesIO` was 1 microsecond).

The `memoryview` solution scales similarly to the `BytesIO` solution, though as of 3.5, it's slightly slower than the `BytesIO` approach (likely a result of the need to construct several temporary `memoryview`s to perform the necessary casting operations and/or the `memoryview` slice assignment code being general purpose for many possible formats, so it's not simple `memcpy` in implementation). `memoryview` might scale better for much larger copies (if the losses are due to the fixed `cast` overhead), but it's rare that you'd have a struct large enough to matter; it would only be in more general purpose copying scenarios (to and from `ctypes` arrays or the like) that `memoryview` would potentially win.

Comment: Side-note: Normally, for file-like objects, I'd use them with a `with` statement; in this specific case of `BytesIO` I omitted it because no real file handles are involved (so even on non-CPython interpreters, it's not a problem if the memory is cleaned up lazily), and using the `with` statement involves significant overhead; on Py 3.5, changing `io.BytesIO(myarr).readinto(mystr)` to `with io.BytesIO(myarr) as bio: bio.readinto(mystr)` roughly doubles the time per initialization in my test case of a 23 field class (314 ns -> 541 ns; trivial cost for real I/O, but not for in-memory fake I/O).

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be an array? could you use a list maybe? you can unpack from a list in to a function you can use the * operator:

mystr = MyStruct(*arr)

or a dict with:

mystr = MyStruct(**arr)

Comment: I could use array.tolist() ill try to do that, nope doesnt work I get: TypeError: one character string expected

Comment: Is there a reason to be using array in your code?

my presented solution meant reengineer the code to use a native data structure like a list or dictionary

Comment: well... an array is the same as a list if I did a .tolist() what you are describing here is unpacking a list or a dictionary for a generic function which is not what I am trying to do. I need an array since I am representing binary data and I am trying to convert it to a ctype struct.

Comment: I think the issue is that the data is coming from a file and I am not sure how this is relates to what you have described vs the readinto call

Comment: @Har: That error you get doesn't make sense given the definitions from your example code. Put something closer to your real code in the question.

Comment: @ShadowRanger okay updated my structure definition to something closer to the real code